# Combining ListBox, Select Case and Range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, offset, userform

I have created a Macro that selects a different item price for different states (because of taxes). To do that, I'm using a Userform containing a ListBox with the possible states. Then, I've put a Select Case to pull the values from the correct column.

However, it seems to not understand the range variables I'm trying to use...
Here is a sample of my code.

> First I declare the Range variable with the Items I'm selling, and
>   then prompt for a Userform with my Listbox of all the states.

```
Dim Items As Range
Set Items = Range("I9").End(xlDown)
Set Items = Range(Items, Items.End(xlDown))

UserForm1.Show
```

> Inside the Userform, I've put a Command Button to execute upon click,
>   where it should offset the "Items" range depending on the state.

```
Select Case Me.ListBox1
    Case "NY"
        Set State = Items.Offset(0, 6)
    Case "CA"
        Set State = Items.Offset(0, 7)
    End Select
Unload UserForm1
```

... and that is when I get the error message:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

Can someone help me understand why I cannot offset my previous declared Range?

Comment: Is your `State` variable declared as a range?  Does your ListBox only have a single item selected?

Comment: It should also be noted that for your code to work, your ListBox must have a `MultiSelect` property of `0 - fmMultiSelectSingle`

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes, `State` variable is defined as Range. I've tried declaring it into the macro itself, and also tried declaring only when the UserForm is opened, but the result is the same.

My ListBox only allow for 1 item to be selected.